# Detecting mismatch between constructor parameter names and property names with immutable objects

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization, immutability

Consider the following mutable object:

```
class SomePoco
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

Let's round trip it through Json.NET:

```
var p=new SomePoco{Id=4,Name="spender"};
var json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p);
var pr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomePoco>(json);
Console.WriteLine($"Id:{pr.Id}, Name:{pr.Name}");
```

All is good.

Now, let's make out POCO immutable and feed values via a constructor:

```
class SomeImmutablePoco
{
    public SomeImmutablePoco(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
    public int Id{get;}
    public string Name{get;}
}
```

... and round-trip the data again:

```
var p = new SomeImmutablePoco(5, "spender's immutable friend");
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p);
var pr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeImmutablePoco>(json);
Console.WriteLine($"Id:{pr.Id}, Name:{pr.Name}");
```

Still good.

Now, let's make a small change to our immutable class by renaming a constructor parameter:

```
class SomeImmutablePoco
{
    public SomeImmutablePoco(int pocoId, string name)
    {
        Id = pocoId;
        Name = name;
    }
    public int Id{get;}
    public string Name{get;}
}
```

then:

```
var p = new SomeImmutablePoco(666, "diabolo");
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p);
var pr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeImmutablePoco>(json);
Console.WriteLine($"Id:{pr.Id}, Name:{pr.Name}");
```

Oh dear... It looks like Json.NET is doing some reflective magic over the names of our constructor parameters and matching them to property names in our POCO/json. This means that our freshly deserialized object doesn't get an `Id` assigned to it. When we print out the `Id`, it's `0`.

This is bad, and particularly troublesome to track down.

This problem might exist in a large collection of POCOs. How can I automate finding these problem POCO classes?

Comment: "How can I automate finding these problem POCO classes?" For there to be a problem, you'd have to have JSON that doesn't deserialize. At that point, you can just test whether or not you can deserialize the JSON. If you're worried that you wouldn't be able to deserialize the result of serializing, that's just a matter of creating a single instance of each class, and checking that a serialize/deserialize round trip works.

Comment: You can put `[JsonProperty("pocoId")]` on `Id` property and it solves the problem. The only way to automate is writing generic unit test that take a list of class and assert each property value.

Comment: @CodeNotFound I like the idea of a unit test that tests this. If all of my POCOs exist in a particular namespace, it might be possible to find them reflectively and test them. I might give it a go and self-answer.

Comment: @CodeNotFound The idea of perpetuating the mismatch via `JsonPropertyAttribute` is a direction I'd rather not take. I'd really like consistency, and am happy to edit any problem classes to eliminate the naming mismatches.

Comment: I wonder how  someone will automate this without passing a list of assemblies, types or namespaces to get the types implied into Json.net serialization/deserialization. I say that because Json.net don't help to configure somewhere that list so types are know by this library only at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that finds such classes using reflection:

```
var types = new List<Type>() { typeof(SomeImmutablePoco) }; // get all types using reflection
foreach (var type in types)
{
    var props = type.GetProperties(bindingAttr: System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (var ctor in type.GetConstructors())
    {
        foreach (var param in ctor.GetParameters())
        {
            if (!props.Select(prop => prop.Name.ToLower()).Contains(param.Name.ToLower()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"The type {type.FullName} may have problems with Deserialization");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. This is where I was headed. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can map your json property like that:

```
class SomeImmutablePoco
    {
        public SomeImmutablePoco(int pocoId, string name)
        {


       Id = pocoId;
        Name = name;
    }

    [JsonProperty("pocoId")]
    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
}
```